# Format json String and pass it to the body with parameters gives error

Tags: c#, api, restsharp

I am trying to create a post request using RestSharp.

I have the following string

```
"{ \"name\": \"string\", \"type\": \"string\", \"parentId\": \"string\", \"Location\": [ \"string\" ]}"
```

I need to pass that into the json body to send a POST request I am trying the following.

```
public IRestResponse PostNewLocation(string Name, string Type, Nullable<Guid> ParentId, string Locatations)
{
  string NewLocation = string.Format("{ \"name\": \"{0}\", \"type\": \"{1}\", \"parentId\": \"{2}\", \"Location\": [ \"{3}\" ]}", Name, Type, ParentId, Location);
  var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
  request.Resource = string.Format("/Sample/Url");
  request.AddParameter("application/json", NewLocation, ParameterType.RequestBody);
  IRestResponse response = Client.Execute(request);
}
```

And the error

```
Message: System.FormatException : Input string was not in a correct format.
```

How can I format the above string to pass it into the json body?

My Test fails at this line

```
string NewLocation = string.Format("{ \"name\": \"{0}\", \"type\": \"{1}\", \"parentId\": \"{2}\", \"Location\": [ \"{3}\" ]}", Name, Type, ParentId, Location);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got open braces in your format string,  but without them being format items. You *could* use double braces instead:

```
// With more properties of course
string newLocation = string.Format("{{ \"name\": \"{0}\" }}", Name);
```

... but I'd *strongly* recommend that you don't. Instead, produce JSON using a JSON library, e.g. Json.NET. It's really simple, either using classes or anonymous types. For example:

```
object tmp = new
{
    name = Name,
    type = Type,
    parentId = ParentId,
    Location = Location
};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tmp);
```

That way:

- You don't need to worry about whether your name, type etc contain characters that need to be escaped
- You don't need to worry about format strings
- Your code is much easier to read

Comment: Ah yes, Thanks for the other example I will try it out :) FYI you have a typo in `Name` "."

Comment: (Fixed the typo.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the curly braces used at the start and end of your format string (since they have a special meaning). Escape them by adding an additional brace like so:

```
string NewLocation = string.Format("{{ \"name\": \"{0}\", \"type\": \"{1}\", \"parentId\": \"{2}\", \"Location\": [ \"{3}\" ]}}", Name, Type, ParentId, Location);
```